# Autocorrelation in squared residuals means heteroskedasticity?

Tags: residuals, heteroscedasticity

I am wondering whether testing the squared residuals of a regression would provide information on whether there exists heteroskedasticity

Comment: Yes, you can test for *conditional* heteroskedasticity by testing for presence of autocorrelation in squared residuals.

Comment: So there is a distinction between standard heteroskedasticity and conditional?

Comment: I am not sure if *unconditional* heteroskedasticity exists, especially if you pick hard on definitions. But maybe there is an answer somewhere on this site?.. Perhaps an example could be that for time $t$ from 1 through 100 the unconditional variance is 1 and from time $t$ from 101 through 200 the unconditional variance is 2. Then this is heteroskedastic, but can I say it is really *unconditional* (because time $t$ is involved, one is kind of conditioning on it)? I suppose I can.

Comment: I simply want to know if I can test my regression for heteroskedasticity by looking at the autocorrelation of the squared residuals :)

Comment: Do you have time series data? If so, then you can test for *conditional* heteroskedasticity (otherwise known as ARCH effects) using ARCH-LM test or by testing for the presence of autocorrelation in squared residuals.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that my version of EViews is not full, so it only allows me to test for autocorrelation in the residuals, in the squared residuals, and for normality. Unfortunately it does not offer the ARCH-LM test, so I will just use the squared residuals option. Thank you!